# Word add-in multiple production environments

Tags: office-js, word-addins

In order to support multiple production environments for our Word add-in, we need to be able to redirect the user to another server on login.

This is so that the version of the add-in in environment X would always be compatible with our other services (API, etc.) in the same environment.

A sample setup would be:

- **Default Word Add-in** (e.g. located at [domain].com - this is the URL in SourceLocation on the manifest)
- **Production 1 Word Add-in** (e.g. on Version 1.0.0, located at subdomain1.[domain].com)
- **Production 2 Word Add-in** (e.g. on Version 2.0.0, located at subdomain2.[domain].com)

The intention is for the user to login via the **Default Add-in** and then be redirected within the taskpane to **Production 1** or **Production 2**.

Is it possible to redirect the user to another instance on the Word add-in within the taskpane?

In Word online, when redirecting with `window.location.href`, the following error occurs:
"Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in. Please try again later or contact your system administrator."

On desktop Word on Mac, `window.location.href` simply opens a browser window on the new location instead of loading it in the taskpane.

Thanks,

Morgan

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, please see if an ordinary <A ...> link to the subdomain works in the task pane.

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be that all of the Word plugin subdomains needed to be registered in the manifest file under "AppDomains." After that, redirecting from subdomain X to subdomain Y worked just fine.

Comment: Nice one, way to go!